# How to make dlerror() report *all* unresolved symbols from dlopen() failure to load shared library?

Tags: linux, dlopen

I'm trying to report all unresolved symbols from a failed call to dlopen() on a shared library. I've tried both RTLD_LAZY and RTLD_NOW as flags to the dlopen call. I know the shared library has 10 missing symbols (i.e. if you performed a static link g++ blah blah : the link would fail with 10 missing symbols). I want to get dlerror() to tell me about all of the 10 missing symbols during the failed load.

Does anyone know how to coax this into happening? I see from the man pages that dlerror() returns the last error; so maybe I'm asking too much but wondered if anyone knows.

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 5):

> I want to get dlerror() to tell me about all of the 10 missing symbols during the failed load.

You can't: the loader reports the error *as soon as* it discovers that the library can't be loaded (i.e. as soon as it discovers the first missing symbol). There is no point for the loader to go any further, and so it doesn't.

However, you can simulate what `ldd -r` does, by using `LD_PRELOAD` and `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS`, to get the complete answer. Example:

```
$ cat main.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  void *p = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);
  if (p == NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", dlerror());
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}


$ cat foo.c
int bar(), baz();  // not defined anywhere
int foo() {
  return bar() + baz();
}

$ gcc main.c -ldl; gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo.c

$ ./a.out
./foo.so: undefined symbol: baz  # only the first symbol is reported

$ ldd -r ./a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff52ddc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f158e48d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f158e0ce000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f158e6b2000)
```

That doesn't work, because your program never executed, and thus never loaded `foo.so`. But `LD_PRELOAD` to the rescue:

```
$ LD_BIND_NOW=1 LD_WARN=1 LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 LD_PRELOAD=./foo.so ./a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3c1b6000)
    ./foo.so (0x00007ffd33212000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffd3300e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffd32c4f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffd33414000)
undefined symbol: baz   (./foo.so)
undefined symbol: bar   (./foo.so)
```

Voilà: all unresolved symbols now reported.